# Docker windows Cannot find module with ../../ and file src

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, rest, dockerfile

I need to build a node js application with docker in windows, but after build images when i run docker image i have this error but i don't have any idea about this solution.I’ve tried with other solutions but nothing seems to work for me.

```
FROM node:14
# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3001
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and this is the error after running the image :

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../../email/EmailVerification'
Require stack:
- /usr/src/app/src/api/v1/users/User.controllers.js
- /usr/src/app/src/api/v1/users/Auth.routes.js
```

this is my package.json :

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esdy4.png)

and this is my project sturcture:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQTNe.png)

Comment: Do you have any volume mappings when you run the image and if you do, what path(s) do you map it/them to?

Comment: i don't have any volume or docker-composer i just run `docker build -t node .
docker run -p 3001:3001 node`

Comment: To help, I think we need to see the dependencies defined in your package.json and the code that fails. There must be a `require` statement for EmailVerification in User.controllers.js. Your Dockerfile looks fine to me.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the information there. Text formatting in the comments section is horrible :)

Comment: This is my package.json : 
[link](https://i.imgur.com/tKuwMwn.png)

and this is my project sturcture:
[link](https://i.imgur.com/Wg3IKDB.png)

Comment: Have you looked at `src/api/v1/users/User.controllers.js`? Does it contain a require statement for EmailVerification?

Comment: Anyway, I think your issue is that you have a lower-case e in 'email' wherever you reference the EmailVerification module as seen in the error message `../../../email/EmailVerification`. But if you look at your directory structure, the Email directory is using an upper-case 'E'. That works on Windows because the Windows filesystem isn't case sensitive. But Linux' is. So they have to match.

Comment: Nice . I sincerely appreciate by your comment @Hans Kilian YOU SAVE MY DAY . Thank you very much.